# android main thread blocked by itself when using sqlite

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, deadlock

here is the trace found in anr.txt

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41663508 self=0x412e3b58
  | sysTid=7186 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075322672
  | schedstat=( 52016072596 286093565179 144215 ) utm=4431 stm=770 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x416635d8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:680)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:349)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:586)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.cache.CacheDBProvider.query(CacheDBProvider.java:202)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.cache.CacheDBProvider.query(CacheDBProvider.java:190)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.cache.service.PictureUrlCacheService.query(PictureUrlCacheService.java:45)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.util.PicUrlUtil.getOldUrl(PicUrlUtil.java:77)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.util.PicUrlUtil.getOldUrlMid(PicUrlUtil.java:25)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.profile.MoreViewGenerator.setImg(MoreViewGenerator.java:824)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.profile.MoreViewGenerator.initAccountPic(MoreViewGenerator.java:818)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.profile.MoreViewGenerator.refreshUIData(MoreViewGenerator.java:1108)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.profile.MoreViewGenerator.onResume(MoreViewGenerator.java:1059)
  at com.lenovo.vcs.weaver.main.NavigationActivity.onResume(NavigationActivity.java:178)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
  at com.qihoo360.mobilesafe.loader.b.callActivityOnResume(SourceFile:123)
  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5265)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Usually I will try to find out what the object-holding thread was doing, in this case I can not do it this way, as you can see the main thread is blocked by the only main thread itself, and I don't think it is theoretically possible.

I know it not a good practice of doing database things in main thread, and I plan to correct that.

So far I can only find it in Android 4.4, and I am not sure if the problem only happened in main thread. Has anyone encountered this problem, or just me has this kind of luck.

Comment: can you please share your code..

Comment: Turn on StrictMode with penaltyDeath active. You'll find out where its happening real quick. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: I've planned to do the database thing other than in the main thread, while it doesn't solve the problem, whatever thread runs the code hangs. This problem does not happen every time.